# Print branch name with git rev-list

Tags: git

I'm writing a script and I need to feed it with a **paging** list of branches in a repo.

The only `git` command I could find that can handle refs with a `--max-count` and a `--skip` parameter, which are the essential components of paging results, is a `rev-list`. But I can't find an equivalent to the `refname` for the `--format` argument of `rev-list`.

This is what I'm trying to do but with a `git for-each-ref` instead:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ \
       --format='%(refname:short) %(objectname:short)'
```

Unfortunately neither `git for-each-ref` nor `git branch` have a `--skip` for paging (only a `--count`), so it's no good for my paging script.

I'm also trying to do this using one command. Using nested/piped commands has a performance hit I'm not willing to take due to the fact that this will run against a long list of historical branches and needs to process by a pages. But I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Every ref points to one and only one commit, which is why `for-each-ref` can be made to act on commit attributes.

But the converse is not true.  Some commits have no refs pointing at them.  Some commits have many refs pointing at them.  So asking `rev-list` to act on ref (e.g. branch) attributes is inherently ambiguous.

I think your best bet is to run `for-each-ref` once, capturing the output to a set of pre-paged files.  Yes the initial run to create the files will involve piped processes (`git for-each-ref` piped to a script that splits out a file for each page); but then requests for individual pages will actually be faster because they won't even have to invoke git.

Comment: ok, but I assumed that since `rev-list` has a `--branches` it means it would list branches only, but I see that's not the case. I'll resort to running `for-each-ref` and piping the output to a pager. I just wish the paging attributes (with string querying) were a standard for every git command.